# Dictionary with multiple values for given key

Tags: tcl

I am trying to implement tcl dictionary with multiple values for given key.

Les say my data is as,

```
John    3   11  13  10  123
David   3   3   45  10  64
Smith   3   5   78  10  679
Hector  3   9   97  10  764
```

1st column is key, subsequent columns are values.

How to define this dictionary ? Also how to retrieve the values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [manual for `dict`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm):

Creating a dict given the text that you have with the key/value pairs might need some looping:

```
foreach line [split $text \n] {
    set words [split $line \t]
    dict set myDict [lindex $words 0] [lrange $words 1 end]
}
```

As for retrieving the values, you can simply use `dict get`:

```
dict get $myDict John
# 3 11 13 10 123
```

Comment: I was writing an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55706059/foreign-key-object-returning-null-in-http-get-request#comment98095178_55706059, could you undelete it?

Comment: @CodeCaster Apologies, I was wrong. I should be going in more depth through the tutorials and take the time to get a better understanding of entity framework. I was mistaken to think that it was something small that I was missing and it showed through the close votes.

Comment: The problem is not necessarily Entity Framework, but the botched N-tier and repository pattern that your predecessor left you with.